# Path to c file in Windows loses all separators while building project in Eclipse

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, makefile, arm

Build of my Arm Cross GCC Project in Eclipse fails attempting to compile source file.

I have this section in *config.mk*:

```
ifeq ($(BUILD_SYS),WINCMD)
$(info Building on Windows $(BUILD_SYS))
export DIR_SEP=\\
```

In the makefile, SRC_PATH is defined like this:

```
export MAIN_DIR = $(APP_DIR)$(DIR_SEP)src
..
SRC_PATH:= $(MAIN_DIR)
```

the rule for building says:

```
%.o: %.c
$(OUTPUT_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.c $(DEPEND_PATH)/%.d
    $(HIDE)echo Compile $< 
    $(HIDE)$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -o $@
```

This works perfectly well in Linux, alas fails in Windows.
When running on Windows I get the following output and error:

> ```
> Compile: C:\projects\my_repo\Projects\My_App/main.c
> arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: C:projectsmy_repoProjectsMy_App/main.c:
> No such file or directory
> ```

**Note**

I had noticed that when I when I echo the $< $(INCLUDE_DIRS) I get the same phenomena and all the directory separators, save last, are gone.

Please advise if you met this issue before.

Comment: How do you set up `SRC_PATH`?

Comment: And unless you have very long paths (longer than 255 characters) or uses Windows-specific UNC paths, there's no need to worry about directory separators. Windows have been able to handle both backward and forward slash since the DOS days.

Comment: Thank you, @Someprogrammerdude I had dded the SRC_PATH definition to the question

Comment: Now I assume you `include` this `config.mk` file somewhere in your main makefile? *Where* do you include it? Before or *after* you use `DIR_SEP` (and create the `MAIN_DIR` variable)? Can you please try to create a [mre] to show us?

Comment: Thanks again, @Someprogrammerdude I will try and create a *reproducible* sample, but, in the meantime - the echo prints the path perfectly while, one line later, the make looses all separators, is there no clue there?

Comment: Just to test, have you tried another backslash for extra escaping? Like "DIR_SEP=\\\\"?

Comment: You should simply always use forward slashes, not backward slashes, in makefiles.  Then you won't have this problem.